# The shape of matrix is correct, but terminal shows 'wrong matrix size'

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch

Here I used bmm() function in pytorch, and the shape of the batch has shown in the picture. As picture shows that the shape of two batches is correct, but why program shows 'wrong matrix size'? Hope your answer :)

```
Ax = adj.bmm(outputs)
```

the shape is:
adj is
torch.Size([1, 22, 22])
outputs is
torch.Size([1, 22, 480])
adj is
torch.Size([1, 22, 22])
outputs is
torch.Size([1, 22, 540])
terminal shows:

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 6: wrong matrix size at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:41

Comment: Question needs clarity. Where's the `picture` you talk about? Why you have given two different shapes for each of `adj` and `outputs`? Which one are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.